# What's the point of Lodash's _.add function?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I guess I'm missing something but why `_.add(x, y)` is better than `x + y` ?

Comment: `_.add()` automatically converts `undefined` values to `0` and tries to convert numeric strings into numbers therefore it can come handy when you do not know for sure whether the values you are trying to sum are defined and their type (e.g. because the data are coming from a third-party API). Here you can see some example of how `x + y` differs from `_.add(x, y)`: https://gist.github.com/yannickglt/e59f8949ab07cae8254d4259545be532

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Operator" functions like `add`, `sub` etc are useful when you need to pass an operator as a callback to some higher order function, for example:

```
array.reduce(add) // compute a sum
array.sort(sub)   // sort array numerically
```

In some languages you can pass an operator directly, e.g.

```
array.reduce(+)
```

but Javascript can't do that, therefore these functions need to be defined somewhere.

For lodash specifically, you can use `_.add` everywhere an "iteratee" is expected, examples from their docs:

```
function square(n) {
  return n * n;
}
 
var addSquare = _.flow([_.add, square]);
addSquare(1, 2);
```

or

```
var zipped = _.zip([1, 2], [10, 20], [100, 200]);
// => [[1, 10, 100], [2, 20, 200]]
 
_.unzipWith(zipped, _.add);
// => [3, 30, 300]
```